# Ode23, ode45, and ode113 in Scilab

Tags: ode, scilab

I am solving ODE by using ode23, ode45 and ode113 in Scilab, I am going to compute the mean absolute error to check which one is more accurate, but all solvers give the error is equal to 0 and the vector length is the same for all of them n=100. I see there is something wrong here and it does not match with MATLAB results. can you help, please? I am going to attach my code.

```
clear
function [v] = functiondifference(t,y,exact)

    [row,column] = size(t); // size(A) returns the dimensions of a matrix A. In our case t is a column vector
    for k = 1:row
       v(k) = feval(t(k),exact) - y(k);   /////////////////////note
    end
endfunction
function y = exact(t)

  y = -3-exp(-sin(t)/2);

endfunction
function yp=de(t,y)
    yp=-(3+y/2)*cos(t)
endfunction

function dydt=f(t,y)
    y=y(1);
    dydt=[ -(3+y/2)*cos(t)]
endfunction
t=linspace(0,%pi);
y0=-4;
//ode 23
y = ode("adams", y0, 0, t, f);   //t0=0
err=functiondifference(t,y,exact)
Error=mean(abs(err))
L=length(y)
disp(L)
//ode 45
y1 = ode("rkf", y0, 0, t, f);
err1=functiondifference(t,y,exact)
Error1=mean(abs(err1))
L1=length(y1)
disp(L1)
//ode 113
y2= ode(y0, 0, t, f);  
err2=functiondifference(t,y2,exact)
Error2=mean(abs(err2))
L2=length(y2)
disp(L2)
```

---

Thanks for your help. the exact solution is correct for the given differential equation yp=0.5*(3+y)*cos(t) and still the output is not correct even after changing in the function to  [row,column] = size(t'). I am going to attach [image]MATLAB results and the exact solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Errors/misconceptions:

- You write in the comment that `t` is a column vector. But actually it is a row vector. Thus you do exactly one difference computation, and that on the initial value where there is no difference. Easiest fix, use the transpose of `t` to make the assumption true:

  ```
    [row,column] = size(t');
  ```
- Your exact solution is not the exact solution of the ODE `yp = -(3+y/2)*cos(t) = -0.5*(6+y)*cos(t)`. After separation this gives

  ```
  6+y(t) = (6+y(0))*exp(-0.5*sin(t))
  ```

With both these corrections I get errors `1.953D-07, 4.954D-12, 5.978D-07` for adams, rkf and lsoda

---

As per comment, to get some better insight, enhance the script to count function evaluations and test multiple error tolerances

```scilab
clear
function y = exact(t)
  y = -6+2*exp(-sin(t)/2);
end//function

global fcnt;

function yp=de(t,y)
    global fcnt
    fcnt = fcnt + 1;
    yp = -(3+y/2)*cos(t)
end//function

t=linspace(0,%pi,10);
y0=exact(t(1));

method=["lsode","adams","rkf","stiff"]
for k = 1:4
    for j=5:8
        tol = 10^(-j);
        fcnt = 0;
        if k==1
            y = ode(y0, 0, t, 0.1*tol, tol, de); 
        else
            y = ode(method(k), y0, 0, t, 0.1*tol, tol, de);   //t0=0
        end
        err=y-exact(t);
        Error=mean(abs(err));//*t(length(t));
        printf("%6s: toll=%6.3g, err=%6.3g, fcnt=%6d\n",method(k),tol,Error,fcnt)
    end
end
```

This results in the table

```
 lsode: toll= 1e-05, err=2.32e-05, fcnt=    57
 lsode: toll= 1e-06, err=5.81e-07, fcnt=    63
 lsode: toll= 1e-07, err=8.43e-08, fcnt=    81
 lsode: toll= 1e-08, err=6.41e-08, fcnt=   107
 adams: toll= 1e-05, err=2.21e-05, fcnt=    40
 adams: toll= 1e-06, err=5.88e-07, fcnt=    47
 adams: toll= 1e-07, err=7.45e-08, fcnt=    58
 adams: toll= 1e-08, err=4.29e-08, fcnt=    72
   rkf: toll= 1e-05, err=7.35e-07, fcnt=    61
   rkf: toll= 1e-06, err=7.39e-07, fcnt=    61
   rkf: toll= 1e-07, err=2.24e-07, fcnt=   113
   rkf: toll= 1e-08, err=2.35e-08, fcnt=   132
 stiff: toll= 1e-05, err=2.70e-05, fcnt=    72
 stiff: toll= 1e-06, err=3.40e-06, fcnt=    60
 stiff: toll= 1e-07, err=5.09e-07, fcnt=    87
 stiff: toll= 1e-08, err=1.55e-07, fcnt=   121
```

- The methods meet the accuracy goal
- "RKF" does not use intra-step interpolation, so implicitly has the step size of the output samples as upper bound for the internal step size. This leads to more function calls than necessary.
- "adams" is indeed the cheapest method, but as explicit solver
- the situationally implicit solvers "default/lsode" and "stiff" have a comparable profile in the middle, apparently the implicit steps allow a slightly larger step size, else one would expect a doubling of the count from the explicit multi-step method "adams".

Comment: Comparing solvers like this is not very informative, as they all control (approximately) the local error (relative or absolute). What you can compare is the solver efforts (e.g. by measuring the elapsed cpu time) to reach a given tolerance. The ode() help page explains how to change the default tolerances.

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet : I've since added a more detailed run of test cases. I'm aware that the ODE used is not very representative for comparing the strengths of the methods, but it was the question asked.

Comment: My comment was written before you updated your answer, I already upvoted it.

Answer (score -1):

The exact solution of the given DE
[image: The exact solution of the given DE]

Comment: Yes, that is also correct, but is not the equation you use in your code. There is a difference between `(3+y/2)` and `(3+y)/2`.

Comment: Please include your code as formatted text instead of an image

Comment: Thank you very much@ Lutz Lehmann. Can you please explain to me which method in ["lsode","adams","rkf","stiff"] is equivalent to ode23, ode45, and ode113. If I would like to compute a single value of the mean absolute error (not range as was given) for each method and the vector length like MATLAB results to compare between three methods, how can I change this code to do this?

Comment: I included my Scilab code in the previous comments@jrswgtr

Comment: That is not possible in Scilab, you can not get an output based on the internal steps like in Matlab. ((Note that Matlab uses a `"Refine"` parameter that defines how many points are sampled via interpolation for each internal step.))

Comment: Switching my code to the intended DE does not change the reported error values substantially and reduces the number of function evaluations at the high end, without changing the overall qualitative picture. There has to be another error in your scilab code